# wxPython: Create multicolored text widget for ASCII game

Tags: wxpython

How to create a readonly multicolored text widget like a StyledTextCtrl, but without scrollbars, borders etc? It should be just a widget that allows to paint different parts of text by different colors, nothing more...

Maybe wxPython is not the best solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wx.TextCtrl with the TE_RICH style flag and set it up so it doesn't have any borders. Or you could use the HTMLWindow.